# set to vs set at

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

When talking about odds, say in sports, should I say

"Betn1 set Team A's odds at 10/1"

or

"Betn1 set Team A's odds to 10/1"?

Comment: The odds are 10 to 1. Generally, odds do not take the verb set, though it could. It is somewhat awkward. John **put the odds at 10 to 1**. set sounds like programming and suchlike.

Answer (score -1):

There is no useful difference. In this case "set at" and "set to" mean exactly the same.

Extended context might change that, but that would also change the Question.

Comment: Doubt what you like and don't you think the only difference would be that "set to" jut might mean "changed to"?

Comment: Google n-grams says "set the odds at" is vastly more common than "set the odds to"; I agree both mean the same, but the question isn't asking what they mean.

Comment: @StuartF Sorry; the Question is either asking what they mean, or has no useful point.

 Is that really not obvious?